# refresh dynamic php div using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, loading

I print mysql result into div using php/while loops. now i need to refresh this result after click any link, button using jquery plugin or code . better design after click link, user see any loading message ( please wait ) and jquery/php print new result ( refresh div ). Is this possible? There is a way to do this?

My div is :

```
<a class="click" href="#"> Link TO refresh Div </a>
<div class="messagelist">
<?PHP $result=mysql_query("select * from messages where id<'$lastmsg' order by id desc limit 20");
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
<div class="commentbox">
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{?>
<li>
<?php echo $row['id'] . ' #' . $row['date'] . ' / ' . $row['comment']; ?>
</li>
<?PHP } ?>
</div>
</div>
```

**`NOTE : I dont need To Load From Jquery External File Methods . thanks`**

Comment: Actually, in fact i dont have idea. im amateur in jquery. thanks for What have you tried !

Answer (score 2):

Your script can't work. You are mixing PHP and HTML:

```
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
<div class="commentbox"> /*THIS IS WRONG*/
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
```

I think this is what you want:

Create a new PHP file which only outputs your list. Call it, for example, `list.php`.

Content of main file:

```
<a class="click" href="#"> Link TO refresh Div </a>
<div class="messagelist">
<div class="commentbox">
<ul>
<?PHP $result=mysql_query("select * from messages where id<'$lastmsg' order by id desc limit 20");
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{?>
<li>
<?php echo $row['id'] . ' #' . $row['date'] . ' / ' . $row['comment']; ?>
</li>
<?PHP } ?>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Content of `list.php`:

```
<?PHP $result=mysql_query("select * from messages where id<'$lastmsg' order by id desc limit 20");
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{?>
<li>
<?php echo $row['id'] . ' #' . $row['date'] . ' / ' . $row['comment']; ?>
</li>
<?PHP } ?>
```

Add this to the `<head>` part of the main file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('.click').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.messagelist').text('Please wait...');
        $('.messagelist').load('list.php');
    });
});
</script>
```

to load the content.

Comment: i dont need to this method : loading external pages. using same page. but thanks for answer.

Comment: it's not possible without a second file.

Answer (score 2):

Add an `onclick` to your element:

```
<a onclick="loadPhp();">Reload php function</a>
```

create the `javascript` function:

```
function loadPhp(){
    //set a variable for the php function
    var func = <?php yourphpfunction();?>;
    //append the php function results to a div using jquery
    $(element).html(func); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want you'll need to use Ajax.

1.Create a separate PHP-file that contains your mysql result, the html-snippet that is created below.

Contents of **messages.php**:

```
<?PHP $result=mysql_query("select * from messages where id<'$lastmsg' order by id desc limit 20");
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
<div class="commentbox">
<ul>
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{?>
<li>
<?php echo $row['id'] . ' #' . $row['date'] . ' / ' . $row['comment']; ?>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<?PHP } ?>
```

2.If you're using jQuery the [ajax-request](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) is pretty simple. Add the following to your current page (leave your current page otherwise as it is):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.click').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.messagelist').html('Please wait...');
        $.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            url : 'messages.php',
            dataType : 'html',
            success : function (response) {
                $('.messagelist').html(response);    
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I haven't tested the code above but it should work.

Comment: using jquery external load/document is ready my jquery library and other code not work with external page when load in my page.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you're trying to say. Is ajax not an option for you? All you're doing is adding some javascript to your main file and creating a separate php file.

Comment: There is a mistake in the PHP code. Take a look at my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054595/refresh-dynamic-php-div-using-jquery/10054668#10054668).

Comment: @Alex: You mean the missing </div>? The <ul>s were also missing.