# jquery code work when load external page into div

Tags: jquery

I found this question/answer for [refresh dynamic php div using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054595/refresh-dynamic-php-div-using-jquery). [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10054668/1122111) and [TJ.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10054661/1122111) answers to this question. twice methods worked for me! but i have big problem when load external page to my div my jquery library and other jquery code not work for me :(. i need to fix this .

example load 1:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.click').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('.messagelist').html('Please wait...');
            $.ajax({
                type : 'GET',
                url : 'messages.php',
                dataType : 'html',
                success : function (response) {
                    $('.messagelist').html(response);    
                }
            });
        });
    });
 <a class="click" href="#"> Link TO refresh Div </a>
 <div class="messagelist">
 <div class="togglespan"><span>+</span></div>
 <div class="togglediv"></div>
 </div>
```

load 2 :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('.click').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('.messagelist').text('Please wait...');
            $('.messagelist').load('list.php');
        });
    });
    </script>
    <a class="click" href="#"> Link TO refresh Div </a>
    <div class="messagelist">
    <div class="togglespan"><span>+</span></div>
    <div class="togglediv"></div>
    </div>
```

Now for example i have this code for toggle div in my page. this not worked . really in my external page i need to toggle div. how to fix load external page for worked jquery library and code for all external page ?? There is a fundamental way to do this. Thanks

```
$(".togglespan").click(function () {
    if ($(this).next(".togglediv").is(":hidden")) {
        $(this).next(".togglediv").slideDown("slow");
        $(this).children('span').html('+');
    } else {
        $(this).next(".togglediv").slideUp("slow");
        $(this).children('span').html('-');
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you want. Is `.togglespan` loaded from the second PHP-File?

Comment: yes! in both file ( index/first file and external page ). this problem is for other jquery code. in fact , Jquery library And All Plugin And Code not joined to the second page ( external page )

Answer (score 0):

You need event delegation. Try this instead of your toggle code:

```
$(".messagelist").on('click', '.togglespan', function (e){
    if ($(this).next(".togglediv").is(":hidden")) {
        $(this).next(".togglediv").slideDown("slow");
        $(this).children('span').html('+');
    } else {
        $(this).next(".togglediv").slideUp("slow");
        $(this).children('span').html('-');
    }
});
```

Comment: not work ! my problem with jquery toggle code ? or code of loading external page ? i have this problem with other jquery code.